# Running GridSearch over voting classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Trying to run gridsearch over a voting ensemble combining a few classifiers. I keep encountering the same error when running my code

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter n_estimator for estimator GradientBoostingClassifier(criterion='friedman_mse', init=None,
              learning_rate=0.1, loss='deviance', max_depth=3,
              max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
              min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
              min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
              min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100,
              n_iter_no_change=None, presort='auto', random_state=1,
              subsample=1.0, tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1,
              verbose=0, warm_start=False). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Here is the code I have:

```
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1)
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)
ada = AdaBoostClassifier(random_state=1)
gdb = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=1)
eclf = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('dtc',dtc),('rfc',rfc),
                                          ('ada',ada),('gdb',gdb)],voting='hard')
#tuning parameters with gridsearch
params = [{'gdb__n_estimator':[10,20]}]
grid_search = GridSearchCV(eclf,params,cv=5,scoring='accuracy')
grid_search.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking more closely, you'll see that the actual name of the parameter is `n_estimators` (plural); so, your `params` should be:

```
params = [{'gdb__n_estimators':[10,20]}]
```

i.e. it is just a typo.